# Why AIML is considered as a pattern matching? Not a string matching?

Tags: pattern-matching, chatbot, string-matching, aiml

AIML doesn't really care about subject, predicate or object, it cares about what we defined is as a response for chatbot to answer, does it feels like a string matching? Why do we call it as AIML Pattern Matching?

Answer (score 0):

Because it matches patterns rather than strings. Let's say you had a category with a pattern of:

```
<pattern>WHAT IS *</pattern>
```

and someone asked "WHAT IS YOUR NAME". If the bot searched for this string, we wouldn't find anything, so the bot searches for patterns that match the user input.